# De Morgan's Law and $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ are clopen

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The [book](http://www.math.louisville.edu/~lee/RealAnalysis/)'s definitions of open and closed sets (definition 5.1) are:

A set $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open if $\forall x \in G: \exists \varepsilon > 0: (x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subset G$.

A set $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed if the complement of $F$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) is open.

---

Given $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ are both open sets, de Morgan's law show they are also closed sets (corollary 5.3).

Why does applying de Morgan's law show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book says that if you apply DeMorgan laws to theorem 5.2, you get corollary 5.3.

What they meant is that you need to apply DeMorgan laws only to **part b and c** of the theorem.

Part (a) follows from definition: since $\emptyset $ is open and it is the complement of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}$ is closed by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathbb{R}^c=\varnothing$ is open whence $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. Similarly,  $\varnothing^c=\mathbb{R}$ is open whence $\varnothing$ is closed

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with de Morgan's law.

Just note that $\mathbb{R}$ being open (quite trivial) implies that $\mathbb{R}^\complement = \emptyset$ is closed.

And the fact that $\emptyset$ is open (it's a void $\forall$-clause) implies
that $\emptyset^\complement = \mathbb{R}$ is closed.